# How to make an array of Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File?

Tags: c#, arrays, google-drive-api

I'm writing a program to upload file/folder structures to the Google Drive. One of the things I want to do which would greatly help my code is make some arrays of Files.

Every time I tried, I would get a nullReferenceException so then I took away everything array related and it worked, so I know it's because I'm trying to make an array.

Does anybody know how to create an array of Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File?

Code:

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File bigFolder= new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File[] underFolder= new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            bigFolder.Title = "Folder Title";//used to get a NullReferemceException here, but then made it not an array
            bigFolder.Description = "The folder";
            bigFolder.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
            bigFolder.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = biggerFolder.Id } };
            bigFolder = service.Files.Insert(bigFolder).Execute();

            underFolder[i].Title = nom[i];//Now get a NullReferemceException here because it's an array
            underFolder[i].Description = "The other folder";
            underFolder[i].MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
            underFolder[i].Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = bigFolder.Id } };
            underFolder[i] = service.Files.Insert(underFolder[i]).Execute();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and needed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is just that, a `NullReferenceException`. Before trying to assign an element of an array that's a non-value type you should make sure you initialize that value. Example: Before assigning `underFolder[i].Title = nom[i];` just initialize that `Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File`.

For completion of answer, this should work:

Also I wouldn't assign the `bigFolder`  variable every time you execute the loop. Instead of directly assigning each Property of each File you can just use an object initializer.

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File bigFolder = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File
{
    Title = "Folder Title",
    Description = "The folder",
    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
    Parents = new List<ParentReference>() {new ParentReference() {Id = biggerFolder.Id}}  
};
bigFolder = service.Files.Insert(bigFolder).Execute();

Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File[] underFolder = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    underFolder[i] = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File
    {
        Title = nom[i],
        Description = "The other folder",
        MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
        Parents = new List<ParentReference>() {new ParentReference() {Id = bigFolder.Id}}
    };
    underFolder[i] = service.Files.Insert(underFolder[i]).Execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already figured it out by using List<File> instead but this should work too!

Comment: Yeah, I generally use Lists instead as well as they have more flexibility.